# Trek Mamba 2013. 1x11 upgrade

Tags: crankset, cassette, drivetrain

I would like to know if it is worth and possible to upgrade a 2013. Trek Mamba from a 3x9 to a 1x11.

Rear hub: Formula DC22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? Yes. Worthwhile? Probably.

You would need to buy a new rear derailleur, the cassette and the crankset (you may reuse the cranks with a new front cog, the tricky part is to get a good chain line, similar to the one you have now with the middle front cog) and of course a new chain.

Rear Hub is fine, it can accomodate a relatively cheap Sunrace 11-50 11-speed cassette.

The dismounting/mounting work is something you can do, no specific trouble, you will need to have 3 specific tools (for cranks and cassette) which will increase the budget needed of about 50/60 $/£/€.

On one hand, doing this you will spend *xxx*$/£/€ and get the bike you are familiar with, upgraded to a nice 1x11 speed system and you personally will understand a bit more of bicycle manteinance&co.

On the other hand, I think the Trek Mamba is a entry model with rather standard components, so it may be worthwhile to buy a used mtb for 2 times (or even 3 times) the amount *xxx* with similar geometry and a 1x11 system already installed ... if the "new" bike fits you, you are good to go, sell the Trek Mamba and you recover a bit of money, otherwise you can be almost sure that you can swap the 1x11 components to your Trek Mamba and viceversa and sell the "new" bike for something around *xxx*.

Comment: Thanks  for your detailed answer!! As you mentioned it is an entry level bike, so I must decided between investing some money in it ( new drivetrain, dropper post etc.) or simply go for a new XC bike....

Comment: @dmak2709 I personally ride an even simpler Scott Tampico from 2006, I did similar upgrades to the one you plan by buying the used parts and installing them by myself. I learned a lot, I did not spend that much (in total, I spent something halfway between buying the new parts and the raw price of the used parts) but sometimes I had the bike out of order for days or even weeks because I was missing missing some small parts or the time to complete the replacement ... so I was glad I had another spare bike (an even older commuting bike)

Comment: @dmak2709 I forgot to mention: you need also a new shifter for the new rear deraileur, and a new cable to connect them.

Comment: thank you! May I ask you if all bottom brackets are compatible with every crankset or bike frame

Comment: Sadly no, There are more BB and crankset types now than ever. Way more than i can describe in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the same bike right now. Using the SRAM NX group with GX crank.    Just took the old bottom bracket out today.   If you do that you’ll need a ISIS/octalink splined tool. Take out the drive side first as it’s metal and less likely to strip.  Clean the groves with a sharp object.  Drive side came out easy.  Non-drive side is plastic and easily strips the grooves.  I used a large C clamp to keep pressure on the tool when removing.

I also changed the rear wheel as I badly buckled the original recently.  That then allowed me to put on the 12 speed cassette.   The bike shop told me it would not fit the original hub.

Edit to add: just noticed to said 11 speed (not 12)...bike shop thought it possible to put 11 speed on exiting hub but I needed new wheel anyway.

Comment: What type of BB do I need?